# Why backdrop filter: blur(5px) is breaking my design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Today I am facing a vey weird issue in css `backdrop-filter: blur(7px);`

First look at first snippet

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
p {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #8f656514;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.1px #393939;
  margin: auto;
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.common {
  margin: 35px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #7f5b5b;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  /* display: contents; */
}

.in {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #3a3b3c45;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0.5px #918b90;
  height: 50px;
}

.bug {
  height: 26px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* width: 50%; */
  bottom: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /* bottom: 500px; */
  border-radius: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="one common">
            <p>First Container</p>
            <div class="in">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two common">
            <p>second Container</p>
            <div class="in bug">
                blurred overflow
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="three common">
            <p>Third Container</p>
            <div class="in ">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

as You are seeing there are 3 containers .
every container have a blurred container by `backdrop-filter: blur(7px);`

but 2nd container's blurred element is overflowing the parent .

Till now everything is working fine .

### First weird thing

by positioning absolute and moving overflowing container towards bottom , it is just lying under
the 3rd containers blurred element while it should be at the top of that blurred element

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
p {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #8f656514;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.1px #393939;
  margin: auto;
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.common {
  margin: 35px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #7f5b5b;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  /* display: contents; */
}

.in {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #3a3b3c45;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0.5px #918b90;
  height: 50px;
}

.bug {
  height: 26px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  position: absolute;
 bottom: -142px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /* bottom: 500px; */
  border-radius: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="one common">
            <p>First Container</p>
            <div class="in">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two common">
            <p>second Container</p>
            <div class="in bug">
                blurred overflow
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="three common">
            <p>Third Container</p>
            <div class="in ">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**to see the result please reset the `bootom` css attribute of `.bug` class according to your browser**

[image]

### How it's gone

I just removed the `backdrop-filter` property from  3 blurred container  .

[image]

**to see the result please reset the `bootom` css attribute of `.bug` class according to your browser**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
p {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #8f656514;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.1px #393939;
  margin: auto;
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.common {
  margin: 35px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #7f5b5b;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  /* display: contents; */
}

.in {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #3a3b3c45;
  /* -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px); */
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(7px); */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0.5px #918b90;
  height: 50px;
}

.bug {
  height: 26px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /* bottom: 500px; */
  border-radius: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="one common">
            <p>First Container</p>
            <div class="in">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two common">
            <p>second Container</p>
            <div class="in bug">
                blurred overflow
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="three common">
            <p>Third Container</p>
            <div class="in ">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Another weird thing with backdrop filter is --

with backdrop filter the overflowing element is on the top of the first container's blurred element instead on the behind of it

[image]

**to see the result please reset the `bootom` css attribute of `.bug` class according to your browser**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
p {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #8f656514;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.1px #393939;
  margin: auto;
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.common {
  margin: 35px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #7f5b5b;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  /* display: contents; */
}

.in {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #3a3b3c45;
  /* -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px); */
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0.5px #918b90;
  height: 50px;
}

.bug {
  height: 26px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 24%; */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 500px;
  border-radius: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="one common">
            <p>First Container</p>
            <div class="in">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two common">
            <p>second Container</p>
            <div class="in bug">
                blurred overflow
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="three common">
            <p>Third Container</p>
            <div class="in ">
                <p>blurred container </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have no idea what's going on here and why ???

Please help me to understand this

Comment: *while it should be at the top of that blurred element* --> what make think it should be like that?

Comment: this is the default behavior see the first solution !!!

Comment: no, the first and second are two different situation. Adding position:absolute change all the story

Comment: I have added two duplicate explain the painting order. Take the time to read them and you will understand the logical behavior you are facing

Comment: Temani Why didn't you just explain it in answer by leaving the question as it is ?? okay any way I m gonna read that ... thanks for ur time

Comment: because I already gave two very detailed answer. I don't see why I have to repeat myself again